# How to inject values from an array into an object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to extract values from an object (done), which get put into an array (done), then those values are changed (by tweening library) and returned to me as an array of values.

I would like to insert those values back into an object of the same shape from whence they came.

But I'm stuck on something fairly basic, and certainly do-able.

I have an example state, like so (it could be a totally different shape, this is just an example):

```js
var state = { 
  ignore: "me",
  count: 0,
  foo: 10,
  bar: {
    baz: 99
  }
}
```

I have a new state, that I want to pass into my tweening method:

```js
var newState = { 
  count: 100,
  foo: 50,
  bar: {
    baz: 999
  }
}
```

There's a tween library in the `tweenState` method, that produces an array of these values at each "frame" of the animation:

```js
// NOTE: I only pass in the properties I wanna tween!!

myApp.tweenState({ count: 100, foo: 50, bar: { baz: 999 } })

// internally, the tween lib produces something like this on each frame:

tweenedValues = [ 50.1231, 34.43543, 456.4543 ]
```

I would like to insert these tweened values into an object of the same shape as the state object I'm using, to create this on each frame (as per example state above):

```js
tweenedState = { 
  ignore: "me",
  count: 50.1231,
  foo: 34.43543,
  bar: {
    baz: 456.4543
  }
}
```

...so far, I only have this terrible code (called on each frame):

```js
  // make sure tweened values are in an array
  var valuesArr = Array.isArray(tweenedValues) ? tweenedValues : [tweenedValues]
  // this object will hold tween values of current frame/progress, 
  // set to original state for now... we'll update it's values from 
  // valuesArr later
  var tweenedState = self.state
  // set the newState properties with new values from valuesArr
  // (newState is the state passed into the tweenState() method)
  Object.keys(newState).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (typeof newState[key] === "object") {
      Object.keys(newState[key]).forEach(key2 => {
        tweenedState[key][key2] = valuesArr[index]
      })
    } else {
      tweenedState[key] = valuesArr[index]
    }
  })
  console.log("tweenedState: ", tweenedState)
```

Which has these obvious problems:

- not recursive, can't go more than 2 levels deep into an object
- in any case, the line `tweenedState[key][key2] = valuesArr[index]` doesn't set the value as expected
- when I made it into a recursive function, it looped forever and crashed

So, I need a function that takes the array, and inserts the values into the correct place - namely the properties passed in to begin with (which creates the `tweenedState` object).

EDIT: Obviously, the state object may look totally different - the one given is just an example -  It may be many levels deep, and may contain other stuff NOT passed in.. **The key point is that I end up with a state object exactly like the original, but with the tweened values inserted instead.**

And I repeat - the Tween library creates the array of values, not me, not my choice. And yes I know object properties are not always in the same order.

EDIT 2: this code has to be isomorphic - working in recent browsers (don't care about IE) *and* Node 10 or later, ideally without polyfills...

EDIT 3:  NOW SOLVED:

Both NinaScholz and mashi have provided answers that worked for me (after I fixed a bug elsewhere).

Ninas answer has stricter JS version requirements, and is a little less portable than mashis answer. On that basis I have accepted mashis answer, though Ninas answer is very nice, too.

Thanks.

Comment: are you really want to use an array of values an an object for adding values in an order which is mabe not the order of the object? why not use an array of targets additional to the valuse array?

Comment: You sait it, it's _fairly basic_: `tweenedState = { count: tweenedValues[0], foo: tweenedValues[1], bar: { baz: tweenedValues[2] } };`

Comment: Why do you use `Object.keys()`? It's "your" state so you should know the properties of it. Why can't you just do: `state.count = tweenedValues[0]; ...`?

Comment: Andreas - because obviously I need something that can handles states of any shape... So Ibrahim your answer is no good and Nina, I don't control the Tween library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function setTweenedValues(state, values) {
  const reducer = (newState, [key, val]) => {
    newState[key] = val;
    if (typeof val === "number") {
      newState[key] = values.shift();
    }
    if (typeof val === "object") {
      newState[key] = Object.entries(val).reduce(reducer, {});
    }

    return newState;
  };

  const newState = Object.entries(state).reduce(reducer, {});

  return newState;
}

var state = { count: 200, foo: 10, bar: { zzz: 999 }, ignore: "me" },
    tweenedValues = [50.1231, 34.43543, 456.4543],
    tweenedState = setTweenedValues(state, [...tweenedValues]);

console.log(tweenedState);
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer over Ninas answer, only cos it is a little smaller, doesn't need `Object.fromEntries` and it's a bit easier for my little brain to understand.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the entries and call the function again for nested entries.

```js
function setValues(pattern, values) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(pattern)
        .map(([k, v]) => [
            k,
            v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? setValues(v, values)
                : values.length ? values.shift() : v
        ])
    );
}

var state = { count: 200, foo: 10, bar: { zzz: 999 }, ignore: "me" },
    tweenedValues = [50.1231, 34.43543, 456.4543],
    tweenedState = setValues(state, [...tweenedValues]);

console.log(tweenedState);
```

Comment: I get  `TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function`, though it looks like what I want

Comment: which js version are you using?

Comment: this code has to be isomorphic - working in recent browser (don't care about IE) and Node 10 or later

Comment: it works in recent [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I know that... I'll accept your answer and look for a small `Object.fromEntries` polyfill for Node. Thanks.

Comment: ```js
function fromEntries(iterable) {
          return [...iterable].reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
            obj[key] = val
            return obj
          }, {})
        }
```

I used this "ponyfill" and replaced `Object.fromEntries` with `fromEntries`, now working in Node 10. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work :/  It only works if original state contains contains only the properties being tweened - it borks all other properties... Removed as accepted answer.

If the original state contains the following  `{ count: 200, foo: 10, bar: { zzz: 999 }, ignore: "me" }` it breaks when you pass in only `{ count: 200, foo: 10, bar: { zzz: 999 } }`

Comment: it just need to chgeck if no more values are available ... please see edit.

Comment: Nope... Gives me `{ count: 200, foo: 10, ignore: 'meNaN', bar: { zzz: NaN } }`

Comment: please add a greater object and the wanted result ad applying values.

Comment: Note, I've updated my OP to make it a little clearer, in terms in only passing in SOME of the state - only the bits that to be tweened .. In case that helps anyone.

Comment: I found a bug elsewhere in the tween thing, fixed that , then your updated version worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as i see it you have values in an array that are always in a guaranteed order, and you want them as prop values in an object... you could use object destructuring

```
const [count, foo, bar] = tweenedValues;
```

then make object like this

```
let obj = {count, foo, bar}
```

Comment: That does not do what I want - the third value is in the wrong place